# How to delete rows that contains value "Invoiced" in whole worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a lot of Excels from different modules with different column layouts (purchase orders, Sales orders, Production orders, etc.).

I want to delete every row that contains value "Invoiced".

I was able to create simple code where only one column ("J") is checked, but I need whole worksheet to be checked.

```
Private Sub BoomShakalaka_Click()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ow = Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row
    For r = ow To 1 Step -1
        If Cells(r, "J") = "Invoiced" Then Rows(r).Delete

    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

I expect that after I run this function, it will check the whole workbook and delete every row which contains the value "Invoiced".

Comment: You are not very clear in your request... whole worksheet? whole workbook? Either way, I would get all data into an array for each worksheet, get the row numbers to be deleted, then delete them (looping directly over your data can be slow to extremely slow depending how much data you have).

Answer (score 1):

I want to add here my idea of using arrays instead, so you only access the worksheet when you read the data, and then when you delete the rows.

```
Option Explicit

Sub deleteInvoiced()

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .DisplayAlerts = False
End With

Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ActiveWorkbook         'or ThisWorkbook, or the name of the workbook where data is
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim R As Long, C As Long, X As Long
Dim lRow As Long, lCol As Long

Dim arrData

    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        lRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row                     'Get the last row in the current sheet
        lCol = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column           'Get the last column in the current sheet

        arrData = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(lRow, lCol))

        For R = UBound(arrData) To LBound(arrData) Step -1
            For C = UBound(arrData, 2) To LBound(arrData, 2) Step -1
                If arrData(R, C) = "Invoiced" Or arrData(R, C) = "Delivered" Then
                    'Now delete the rows
                    ws.Cells(R, C).EntireRow.Delete
                    Exit For 'Exit here in case multiple "Invoice" or "Delivered" in the same row (WHY?!!). Thanks @Brian.
                End If
            Next C
        Next R
    Next ws

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .DisplayAlerts = True
End With

End Sub
```

PS: There is no error handling, but i leave that to you.

Comment: What if the value `Invoiced` is in multiple columns of the same row? Seems like you need to exit the inner loop?

Answer (score 0):

Loop through every cell within every row within `activesheet.usedrange`:

```
Private Sub BoomShakalaka_Click()
    For r = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
        For Each c In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows(r).Cells
            If c.Value = "Invoiced" Then
                c.EntireRow.Delete
                Exit For
            End If
        Next c
    Next r

End Sub
```

Comment: Is great, unless you have lots and lots of data... this will be proportionally slower.

Comment: I added a second answer.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could do it by using find. This will be faster than my other answer if there is a lot of data:

```
sub BoomShakalaka_Click()
    screenupdating = false
    On Error GoTo exitSub

    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).select

    do while true
        Cells.Find(What:="Invoiced", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
        xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False _
        , SearchFormat:=False).Activate
        Selection.EntireRow.Delete

    Loop

exitSub:
    screenupdating = True
    Exit Sub
end sub
```

Comment: Thank you Greg, it is working great for me. I have one more question. Can i just add "or" if i would like to add another value like for example "Delivered"?

Comment: @Mxurr if is working great for you, probably you don't have lots of data... because using find is about as slow as using for each cell in my experience at least. Anyways, kudos to Greg for coming up with 2 solutions really fast.

Comment: No "or" won't work. IF you have just one more word, just copy and paste the code into a new sub with the word changed. If you have maybe more words, then I would suggest you put a string parameter into the sub definition, so you can call the same sub with different words.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another interesting way. It assumes your data starts in cell `A1` and is contiguous.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestDeleteInvoiced()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim arr As Variant
    Dim arr1() As Variant
    Dim row As Long
    Dim col As Long
    Dim i As Long

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    i = 1
    ReDim arr1(1 To 14)

    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        arr = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion

        For row = UBound(arr, 1) To LBound(arr, 1) Step -1
            For col = UBound(arr, 2) To LBound(arr, 2) Step -1
                If arr(row, col) = "Invoiced" Then
                    arr1(i) = row & ":" & row
                    i = i + 1
                        'This If statement ensures that the Join function is less than 255 characters.
                        If i = 15 Then
                            ws.Range(Join(arr1, ", ")).EntireRow.Delete
                            ReDim arr1(1 To 14)
                            i = 1
                        End If
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next col
        Next row

        ReDim Preserve arr1(1 To i - 1)
        ws.Range(Join(arr1, ", ")).EntireRow.Delete
    Next ws

End Sub
```

Note: Deleting a range of non-contiguous rows cannot exceed a 255 character parameter. [Link](https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/forum/help-forums/excel-general/25944-delete-multiple-rows-non-contiguous)